# Html.TextWriter WriteAttribute is not rendering 2 columns in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, htmltextwriter

I want to to create a table with 2 colums in a row.
Then in the next row I want only 1 colum.
Here is a part of my code:

```
writer.WriteBeginTag("table");
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);

//first row
writer.WriteFullBeginTag("tr");
writer.WriteBeginTag("td");
writer.WriteAttribute("valign", "top");
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
writer.Write("row 1, column 1");
writer.WriteEndTag("td");

writer.WriteBeginTag("td");
writer.WriteAttribute("valign", "top");
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
writer.Write("row 1, column 2");
writer.WriteEndTag("td");
writer.WriteEndTag("tr");

//second row  
writer.WriteFullBeginTag("tr");
writer.WriteBeginTag("td");
writer.WriteAttribute("valign", "top");
writer.WriteAttribute("colspan", "2");
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
writer.Write("row 2, 1 column");
writer.WriteEndTag("td");
writer.WriteEndTag("tr");

writer.WriteEndTag("table");
```

Problem is dat the second row is rendered in 1 column, not in 2 columns.
This is the outputted html

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">Check-out date</td>
<td valign="top">Sunday, March 18, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">You have indicated .... and badge.</td>
</tr>
```

I guess this is wrong:

> writer.WriteAttribute("colspan", "2");

Does somebody know a solution?

Comment: What's with all the `writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);`??? Did you look at the HTML that's been output? Can you post that?

Comment: You can use designer to create tables or u can use table control why this much headache

Comment: @Oded There were other attributes before     writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);    , which I had deleted for the sample code. The generated output is fine except for the problem that I mentioned.

Comment: Please post the output you are getting so we can see what is going on.

Comment: @Prabhavith Yes, I know. I am building a HTML email in a class library project. The class library is referenced in a webforms project.

Comment: I don't see the `colspan` attribute in the output.

Comment: @Oded, that is the problem. It is not generated.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code? Do you see that line being hit?

Comment: @Oded Yes, after your suggestion I did. On my local machine the colspan attribute was generated. So I deployed the dll to the webserver and I works there as well. Can't explain what went wrong.... Maybe it is just me.. not thinking about stepping through the code! I guess I am little tired and shoudl take a break! Many thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `writer.AddAttribute("colspan", "2");` before the `td` tag on the second row.